# Can't run different OSB projects on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, osb, oracle-service-bus

I have 2 projects **A** and **B** on **OSB Eclipse**. I can run **B**, but I'm not able to run **A**, it displays the following message:

> "Only one Oracle Service Bus configuration may be deployed to a
>   server."

I have one server running and have tried stopping and restarting it, as well as setting the same targetted runtime.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so first you have to understand what an Oracle Service Bus configuration is.

Just like Eclipse has the concept of workspaces, OEPE has the concept of an OSB Config. Any projects inside the same OSB config know about each other; projects in different configs do not.

So, generally you create one OSB config, import OSB projects into your workspace, then drag-and-drop the projects into the OSB config. After that, you can deploy the entire OSB config to a local WL server using the `servers` tab, or you can rightclick the project and export to a remote server (or localhost) if you prefer to do it that way.